# Output result to exact number

Tags: excel

I need to create Excel formula that would output closest set number from the average result. I am not sure if I can explain it so well so I am giving an example:

1. These are my step values:

   ```
   1,0
   1,3
   1,7
   2,0
   2,3
   2,7
   3,0
   3,3
   3,7
   4,0
   ```
2. I am using this formula:

   ```
   =AVERAGE(B2:B3:B4:B5)
   ```
3. If values of the fields B2, B3, B4 and B5 are:

   ```
   3,3
   2,0
   1,3
   1,0
   ```

   The AVERAGE will be 1,9
4. What I need is that Excel as output in this field to puts 2,0 instead 1,9 because that is the closest step value from the values I listed above (under 1.)
5. If the value is between two step values I need it to be outputted as higher value (if its 1,5 I need it to be 1,7 - not 1,3).

Does anyone have the idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Are the values always sorted from highest to lowest?

Comment: @pnuts Well, I guess you could say so thanks to people here like you and Barry. I think overall I learned most of the excel tricks from you two :P

Comment: @Jerry: No the values are not sorted. They are random.

Comment: @pnuts: 1.8 is closer to 1.7 than to 2.0 so I need the result to be 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your regional settings use the comma as the decimal separator. My settings use the decimal point, so please adjust when you adapt to your scenario.

Enter the step values into a range of cells, sorted ascending. Assign the range name "Steps" to that range. If the average is calculated in cell B7, you can use this formula to arrive at an adjusted average according to the steps.

```
=IF(LOOKUP(ROUND(B7,1),Steps)=ROUND(B7,1),ROUND(B7,1),LOOKUP(ROUND(B7,1)+IF(MOD(ROUND(B7,1),1)=0.8,0,0.3),Steps))
```

The screenshot shows a few different scenarios. Note that 1.8 gets adjusted to 1.7, not to 2.0

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find closest value (and higher of possible 2) with the following array formula (confirmed with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A1:A10,MATCH(C4+MIN(ABS(A1:A10-C4)),A1:A10,0)),C4-MIN(ABS(A1:A10-C4)))
```

`A1:A10` - step values (order does not matter)

`C4`- average

`Index`/`match` combination checkes if the higher value (with shortest distance) exists, and if it doesn't, the lower value is returned.

Comment: @pnuts no, it doesn't - it returns the nearest value (1.7). It returns the higher one only if the the absolute distance is the same, that's how I understand points 4. and 5. of OP

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your values are sorted ascending your formula is:
`=INDEX(B2:B11,IFERROR(MATCH(<average>,B2:B11,0),MATCH(<average>,B2:B11,1)+1))`
Where  is your average formula or a reference to a cell containing the results.

Comment: No problem, you also explained it. I'm already happy to find time to answer a few questions sometimes.